# Is there anything bad about decorating objects (using Draper) at the start of a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

Draper recommends decorating objects at the end of a controller method or alternatively using their `decorates_associated` method [to automatically decorate them](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#when-to-decorate-objects).

I like the idea of the view explicitly declaring what it expects to receive (granted the rest of Rails doesn't work like this but it still feels nice). I'd therefore prefer to decorate objects at the top of the view rather than at the end of the controller:

**So in users#show I would like to do**:

```
- @user = @user.decorate

%h1= @user.full_name
%p= @user.description
```

***Instead of* decorating in the users controller like this**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
    @user = @user.decorate
  end
end
```

I suspect there's some caching issue with doing things this way round but it feels nice. What if anything am I missing? Is what I'm proposing bad practice?

Comment: It depends. Conventions are important, especially when other developers work on the same codebase (now or in the future). As a developer, I would expect the objects to be decorated in the controller. Likewise, if you take on an existing app that uses `draper`, you should expect the same thing. That reduces the energy in reading the code, and is why conventions should be followed in most circumstances.

Comment: That isn't "declaring what it expects to receive", that's "modifying what it receives". IMO it's counter to the "dumb view" ethos. Views are given data, it's the action's job to set up that data. It's misleading in the controller code, because what's leaving the controller isn't what's being operated on in the view.

Comment: @DamienRoche I completely agree with your conventions point and that alone is a good reason to go with the norm. Dave Newton you're right too but I guess I've never really bought into the dumb views paradigm. I'm not sure why a view wouldn't declare its dependencies though as you say it is the Rails norm. Doing the decoration in the view isn't declaring those dependencies either but at least it's hinting what's required.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very good question, because draper confuses the traditional MVC logic a bit. As you can read in the draper README which you have linked, draper aims to replace cluttered helper definitions with a more structured approach.

However, to which part of M-V-C does this belong to? Draper claims to *decorate* objects, which can be associated to the *representation* part of the software architecture and therefore neither belongs to the *Model* nor does it really fit into the *Controller*.

Following @Damien Roche's comment, it also does not really fit into a *View*, because one usually does not expect a *template file* to perform any more actions on an object than displaying its properties.You also do not define your helpers in the template, right?

To my mind, draper can be seen more like an intermediary that extends the objects a controller has selected for displaying before they reach the view. Following that logic I prefer the usage of the `decorate_assigned` command, because that places the decorations somehow *between* Controller and View.

Additional remark: I know what you mean with 'the view declaring what it wants to receive' but this stands in contrast to the fact, that you usually define **one decoration per model** for the whole application. So there is not so much room for 'special requests'

Comment: I'm not sure I get your last point Peter - the one decoration per model. I like the rest of your logic though. My view of decorators are that they're effectively namespaced helpers. I hate helpers and try to avoid object-specific ones as I find them a weird grab-bag of methods. Perhaps I should work harder with the Draper `decorate_associated` and see how far that gets me :)

Comment: @PeterNixey what I mean with my last point is, that you usually do not define different decoration classes for each view of a single model right? So it's even not very DRY to repeat the call to `.decorate` in every view. About the Helper vs Draper Point: Helpers are also kind of namespaced when you use them correctly. I think draper is more an object-oriented view, while helpers are somewhat a functional approach.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean about the DRYness. I've not achieved that because I've been manually decorating at the end of each controller method which is definitely sub-optimal. Out of interest, how would you namespace helpers? I've never really managed to do that

Comment: Well, Helpers are organized in modules and although it's not the default behaviour of rails >= 3, you can tell Rails to *not* include all helpers for all controllers, but only the one that matches the name of the controller (e.g. `UsersHelper` for `UsersController`) (see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) That is at least controller-wise namespacing, which I think is fine. But still, I prefer the object-oriented approach of draper over the functional approach of helpers